# How to disable null reference checking for a folder

Tags: c#, msbuild, protocol-buffers, nullable-reference-types

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

- I have some `*.proto` files I'm generating using the `<ProtoBuf` MSBuild task from `Grpc.Tools`.
- To the best of my knowledge, this neither supports generating nullable references code nor just putting `#nullable disable` at the top of the file.
- But the project I want to include them in has `Nullable` enabled.

This will produce a bunch of classes where the compiler will treat the references as being non-nullable when they are, in fact, nullable. So I'm trying to come up with ways of dealing with this. Just to complicate things, this is a prototype that may be replicated across many projects, so I'm looking for as simple a solution as possible.

A separate project isn't particularly desirable, so I'm trying to find ways that I could mark the target directory as not being nullable enabled. So, is there a way to set the directive for a folder?

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to somehow mix this flag *within* a project? I've only seen it getting configured as a global flag i.e. applies to all files withing a project.

Comment: "You can't do it" may be the correct answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Seeing https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-reference-types.md#generated-code and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references I'd think that something like inserting a `//<autogenerated` or `#nullable disable` line in each file would do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. The problem being: the code generator doesn't do that. There's probably some truly nasty bit of msbuild you could do to update all the generated files.

Comment: It's not really nasty, a combination of ReadLinesFromFile followed by 2 calls to WriteLinesToFile (first the new line, then the result of ReadLinesFromFile) does the trick.